# How to start myslq if it fails to start due to insufficient space, and the main files eating up space are mysql binary log files

Tags: mysql, debian, apache2, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

My server disk usage looks like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            989M     0  989M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  180M  11% /run
/dev/xda1        59G   57G  9.7M 100% /
tmpfs           998M     0  998M   0% /dev/mhs
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           998M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xda14      124M  278K  124M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/2000
```

And when I search for large files, there's basically 52 binary log files that are ~1.1GB.

I can't start mysql due to insufficient space, so I can't purge binary log files properly (apparently your not allowed to delete them manually).

Server runs on bitnami/wordpress/amazon lightsail.

So, what do I do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the oldest of the 52?

Delete the oldest binlogs until you can get going again.

Add to config

```
expire_logs_days = 7
```

if you would like the binlogs to be kept for only one week.